# Error in curlMultiperform(multihandle): embedded nul in string

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I'm trying to download a vector of links, but I get an error message that I don't know what to do with. Code included, hoping someone has a workaround.

CODE:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML) 
url <- "http://www.etfs.bmo.com/bmo-etfs/"
url.parsed <- htmlParse(url)
links <- xpathSApply(url.parsed, "//table//td/a/@href")[-c(1:3)]
links <- paste0("http://www.etfs.bmo.com", links)
pages <- getURI(links)
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Error in curlMultiPerform(multiHandle) : 
  embedded nul in string: '         \r\n                            </nobr>\r\n                        </td>\r\n\t\t\t        </tr>\r\n\t\t\t        \r\n\t\t\t\t\t        \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t        \r\n\t\t\t\t        \t<tr valign="top" >\r\n\t                \t\t\t\t<td class="highlightText"><strong>Annualized Distribution Yield \r\n\t\t                       \t\t\t\r\n\t\t   \t               \t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t    \t            \t\t\t(Jul 07, 2016)\r\n\t\t           \t       \t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t               \t       \t\t\t \r\n\t\t               \t\t\t\t\t<sup>1</sup></strong>\r\n\t\t               \t\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t            \t\t<td>\r\n                            \t\t<nobr>\r\n   \t                            \t\t\r\n    \t                        \t\t\t\r\n                \t            \t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t        \t         \t\t\t\t2.41%\r\n                        \t    \t\t\t\r\n                           \t\t\t\t \r\n    \t                        \t</nobr>\r\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this took a while but I think i've figure it out.

It turns out that webpage is improperly encoded. It claims to be "ISO-8859-1", but on some pages there is trademark symbol encoded as `\x99` which means it probably really is using the "Windows-1252" codepage. This symbol outside the normal ASCII range kicks off multi-byte character reading and the file quickly becomes messed up.

As far as I can tell, RCurl does not support this encoding natively. But you can still download the file as binary data and then convert it using `iconv` which has more conversion options. This should work

```
raw <- lapply(links, getURLContent, binary=TRUE)
pages <- lapply(lapply(raw,readBin,"characer"), 
    iconv, from="WINDOWS-1252", to="UTF-8")
```

Now I tested this on my Mac. The exact from/to strings may vary by platform. Check the list from `iconvlist()` for a possible replacement for the `from=` value should this not work on your machine.

Comment: Are you sure `iconv()` works with raw inputs? When I run your code I get strings that look like  "0d" "0a" "0d" "0a"

Comment: Thank you @hadley I made a mistake when simplifying the code. You are right, you must first turn the raw into a character.

Comment: I'm assuming now you'll also tell me that `httr` has an easier solution to this ;)

Comment: Interesting - I just pushed a change to httr to use `readBin()` instead of `rawToChar()`. Then you can do `content(r, encoding = "WINDOWS-1252")`.

Comment: BTW I think your explanation is a little too complicated - the error occurs because `rawToChar()` throws an error if there any embedded nulls in the string.

Comment: @hadley But i couldn't find any embedded nulls in the data (specifically i've been looking at `link[2]`). There are no `00` bytes in the data that I can find. The only non-ascii byte i can find is at 46812 and is the `\x99`

Comment: I wouldn't have figured this out on my own. Appreciate the help!

Comment: There are definitely embedded nulls: look at `lapply(raw, function(x) which(x == raw(1)))`